# How to facet a plot_ly() chart?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Using `ggplot2` and `plotly` to make an interactive scatter plot with `facet_wrap()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

g<-iris%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(vars(Species))
ggplotly(g)
```

[image: ggplot2 scatterplot with facet_wrap, rendered in plotly]

Is it possible to "facet" using the `plot_ly()` function? The documentation suggests `subplot()`...

```
p<-iris%>%
  group_by(Species)%>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = "scatter")%>%
  subplot() ##Something else here? 
p
```

[image: how to facet this plot_ly scatterplot?]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1: Facet a `plot_ly` chart using the `do()` and `subplot()` method:

```
library(plotly)
iris%>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(p=plot_ly(., x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = "scatter")) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
```

[image: Plot_ly chart made with group_by() and do() function]

2: Trellis a `plot_ly` chart using the new `dplyr::group_map()` function.

```
library(dplyr)
iris%>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_map(~ plot_ly(data=., x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = "scatter", mode="markers"), keep=TRUE) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY=TRUE)
```