# Histogram + facet_wrap with plotly in R

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

I created a gganimate of a `histogram` + `facet_wrap`, animated by `year`, but now I want to have it in `plotly` so the user can have more control.

Based on the documentation I've found, I have tried to add `frame = year` and `aes(frame = year)` in many places but I couldn't make it work.
I have managed to make it work without `facet_wrap`.

The `gganimate` code that works is this:

```
ggplot(data = peak_season, aes(x = overall)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(~league) +
      transition_states(year, transition_length = 1, state_length = 50) +
      view_follow(fixed_y = TRUE)
```

The regular `ggplot` code looks like this.

```
ggplot(data = peak_season, aes(x = overall)) +
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(~league)
```

[image: ggplot]

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to facet a plot\_ly() chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103196/how-to-facet-a-plot-ly-chart)